# Re-launching a VOIP application from background mode using private API's

Tags: ios, private, iphone-privateapi

To start off with - this app doesn't need to get into the App Store.

I'm thinking something along the lines of the following should work:

```
mach_port_t *p;
void *uikit = dlopen(UIKITPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
int (*SBSSpringBoardServerPort)() = 
dlsym(uikit, "SBSSpringBoardServerPort");
p = (mach_port_t *)SBSSpringBoardServerPort(); 
dlclose(uikit);

void *sbserv = dlopen(SBSERVPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
int (*setAPMode)(mach_port_t* port, const char* appID, BOOL suspended, void* unknown, void* unknown2) = 
dlsym(sbserv, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
setAPMode(p, "com.apple.weather", NO, nil, nil);
dlclose(sbserv);
```

However I'm getting `exc_bad_access`, which is likely due to the fact that it needs an auth token - I could be wrong though.

Alternatively I'm trying using the following:

```
Class $SBApplicationController=objc_getClass("SBApplicationController");

NSLog(@"[$SBApplicationController sharedInstance], %@", [$SBApplicationController sharedInstance]);
```

Sadly the output is null - so I guess this can't be done within the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any solution now?

Comment: @rhodesy22 Hello,can you help me how to use SBSSpringBoardServerPort? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204785/special-api-to-launch-an-app-from-my-application) is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS sandbox will block or kill any process which isn't started by iOS.

Comment: Thanks for that, but using something like the SBSSpringBoardServerPort method is technically having the spring board service action the launch isn't it? I can dim the screen, lock the phone, turn aeroplane mode on and suspend the foremost app using that method.

Comment: 2rhodesy22: SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier and other methods like this require entitlement "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications", which springboard has and custom application doesn't have.