# Can we install any .deb/ .ipa file automatically on iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I have one task to perform where I have to install one .ipa file on jailbroken iPhone devices. The project is related to jailbroken domain so any solution will work but the entire process should be automatic i.e. through coding only. I have found many solution to this but most of them ask to get the root access for app and this thing never worked for me. So is there any idea how to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "automatically"?  Are you building an **app** that will let users download and install other apps?  Sort of like building your own App Store app?  Are you looking for a scripting solution?  Where do the apps to be installed come from (on the device, on a server, what kind of server, etc.)?

Comment: @Nate exactly I have to develop an app store, from where user will browse for different categories apps and will just press the install button so the installation will be there in 2 steps: 
Step 1. it'll download the cracked ipa from our php server and store that ipa suppose in app sandbox. Step 2: Now that app will be automatically be installed on iPhone device just after the successful completion of the ipa download.

Comment: @Nate is there any solution to this or have you under go this type of assignment?

Comment: @Nate shared one mail on your personal email id can you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the function MobileInstallationInstall

You can find some code how to use it here https://github.com/kryhear/IPAInstaller/blob/master/testMobileInstallationInstall/BSViewController.m

It will required you to add entitlement com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI with an array containing "Install".

However, I am not sure whether it will be completely silent or not.